# different landing page based on user location preferences - Joomla

Tags: javascript, joomla

I have a childcare site with a few locations. There is a main landing page for the overall child care organization, and then individual sub-pages for each location.

I am looking to allow users to "Set My Location" so that the next time they log on to the site, they are redirected to the individual location page as a home page.

I have tried to find plugins/components to help with this, we do not want users to have to register, so using "User Group" settings to achieve this is out.

THANK YOU

Answer (score 2):

You have to write system plugin. "onAfterRoute" event do following,

1. Get user ip address
2. Based on Ip address you will get country,city,state,etc..,

   $user_ip = 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx';

   $geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=$user_ip"));
    print_r($geo);
3. Based on country ,state, city you just redirect to your custom page.